# Bi-directional Progression Bar Javascirpt is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a bidirectional bar, one start with negative value the other with positive one. Negative statement in the Javascript code is not working

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h3>Example of Progress Bar Using JavaScript</h3>
<input style="height:50px; width:50px; font-size:30px" type = text id="btn1" name = "btn10" > <span id ="option1" style="font-size:30px">Percentage</span>
<p>Pogress Bar</p>


<div style = "position: relative; left: 500px; top: 10px" id="Progress_Status">
  <div id="myprogressBar"></div>
</div>

<div style = "position: relative; left: 42.5px; top: -10px" id="Progress_Status2">
  <div id="myprogressBar2"></div>
</div>


<br>


<button onclick="Negative_or_Positive()">Start Download</button>

</body>

<script src = "index.js"> </script>
</html>
```

javascript code

```
var i = 0;
var My_Button = (document.getElementById("btn1"))

function update() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myprogressBar");
  var width = parseInt(My_Button.value) || 1;
  element.style.width = width + '%';
}


function update2() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myprogressBar2");
  var width = parseInt(My_Button.value) || 1;
  element.style.width = width + '%';
}


function Negative_or_Positive() {
    if (My_Button.value > 0){
        update()
    }else if (My_Button.value <0) {
        update2()
    }
}
```

css code

```
#Progress_Status {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myprogressBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width .2s;
}


#Progress_Status2 {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myprogressBar2 {
  width: 1%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: width .2s;
}
```

the negative statement is not working. When I place a negative value noone of the two bar is growing.
Someone has any idea of why?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a negative value on the elements width property in your `update2()` function. Because you know the value of the input element is negative at this point you can simply negate the parsed value:

```
  var width = -parseInt(My_Button.value) || 1;
```

I put it all in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncwvtasf/1/) and applied the suggested change